Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner Thread does not work properly
My Web application is using two datasources, both pointing to the same RDBMS server (Oracle) and the same database, aside the JNDI name the only differences in the configurations are the username that determines the database schema for Oracle, and the related password.
As said, both configurations are same, except for the username and password parameters!
But while for the first pool connections won't get (much) older than the value that is configured for maxAge, are the connections for the second pool get older and older, without getting evicted.
Of course the pools are used differently: connections from the first pool are used with a high frequency the whole time the application is up and running, connections from the second pool are mainly used during startup (basically to retrieve the initialisation data); later a connection from this pool is used only once in a blue moon.
Consequently, all connnections in the second pool were created at time of Tomcat startup (or when the application itself came up, but as this is very shortly after Tomcat, this does not make much of a difference).
When I added some test code that pulls (borrows) a connection from the second pool and releases it, this connection was evicted; therefore this could be used as a workaround to get rid of the currently obsolete connections in that second pool.
But of course I want to know why the "Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner" thread is not working on that second connection pool! A thread dump shows that thread, and that it gets alive regularly; obviously, it also works on the first connection pool.
Why not on the second one?
Again, the configuration is the same for both connection pools:
<Resource name="jdbc/data"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="SecureTomcatDataSourceImpl"
          closeMethod="close"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@..."
          username="data"
          password="ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD_1"
          maxActive="50"
          minIdle="3"
          maxIdle="5"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
          validationInterval="30000"
          maxWait="180000"
          initialSize="0"
          maxAge="60000"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="180000"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="180000"
/>

<Resource name="jdbc/config"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="SecureTomcatDataSourceImpl"
          closeMethod="close"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@..."
          username="config"
          password="ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD_2"
          maxActive="50"
          minIdle="3"
          maxIdle="5"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
          validationInterval="30000"
          maxWait="180000"
          initialSize="0"
          maxAge="60000"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="180000"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="180000"
/>

The configured factory is a wrapper around org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory that allows to store the database password in an encrypted manner. For details, refer to "Encrypt tomcat database password - How to avoid Clear Text Password" and "Secure Tomcat DataSourceFactory".
This is the code from org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool that creates the "Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner" thread:
/**
 * Initialize the connection pool - called from the constructor
 * @param properties PoolProperties - properties used to initialize the pool with
 * @throws SQLException if initialization fails
 */
protected void init(PoolConfiguration properties) throws SQLException { // Line 451
    poolProperties = properties;

    //make sure the pool is properly configured
    checkPoolConfiguration(properties);
    ...

    initializePoolCleaner(properties); // Line 470
    ...

    closed = false;
}
...

public void initializePoolCleaner(PoolConfiguration properties) { // Line 557
    //if the evictor thread is supposed to run, start it now
    if (properties.isPoolSweeperEnabled()) {
        poolCleaner = new PoolCleaner(this, properties.getTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis());
        poolCleaner.start();
    } //end if
}

The PoolCleaner class is defined in the same source file at line 1574 and looks like this:
protected static class PoolCleaner extends TimerTask {
    protected WeakReference<ConnectionPool> pool;
    protected long sleepTime;

    PoolCleaner(ConnectionPool pool, long sleepTime) {
        this.pool = new WeakReference<>(pool);
        this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
        if (sleepTime <= 0) {
            log.warn("Database connection pool evicter thread interval is set to 0, defaulting to 30 seconds");
            this.sleepTime = 1000 * 30;
        } else if (sleepTime < 1000) {
            log.warn("Database connection pool evicter thread interval is set to lower than 1 second.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ConnectionPool pool = this.pool.get();
        if (pool == null) {
            stopRunning();
        } else if (!pool.isClosed()) {
            try {
                if (pool.getPoolProperties().isRemoveAbandoned()
                        || pool.getPoolProperties().getSuspectTimeout() > 0) {
                    pool.checkAbandoned();
                }
                if (pool.getPoolProperties().getMinIdle() < pool.idle
                       .size()) {
                pool.checkIdle();
                }
                if (pool.getPoolProperties().isTestWhileIdle()) {
                    pool.testAllIdle(false);
                } else if (pool.getPoolProperties().getMaxAge() > 0) {
                    pool.testAllIdle(true);
                }
            } catch (Exception x) {
                log.error("", x);
            }
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        registerCleaner(this);
    }

    public void stopRunning() {
        unregisterCleaner(this);
    }
}

